# How to search records from a table using keywords?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have a table like this:

```
Products ( 'id', 'name', 'description', 'location' )
```

And a search string:

```
'car 1000 london'
```

Now what I want to do is:

```
bring all records where 'car' exists in 'name' or 'description' or 'location'
and
bring all records where '1000' exists in 'name' or 'description' or 'location'
and
bring all records where 'london' exists in 'name' or 'description' or 'location'
```

How can I search like this..

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In InnoDB

```
  SELECT * FROM products p 
  WHERE (p.name LIKE '% car %' 
     OR p.description LIKE '% car %' 
     OR p.location LIKE '% car %')
UNION 
  -- same query but with '% 1000 %'
UNION 
  -- ditto with '% london %'
```

In MyISAM

```
  SELECT 
    MATCH (p.name, p.location, p.description) AGAINST('car') as relevance,
    p.* FROM products p
   WHERE MATCH (p.name, p.location, p.description) AGAINST('london')   
   ORDER BY relevance DESC
UNION 
  -- same query but with '1000' <<-- see note below
UNION 
  -- ditto with 'car'           <<-- see note below.
```

`Match against` has a minimum length of 5 chars, see:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Comment: Thats just for one of the search criteria

Comment: Also he is saying exists which does not translate to a LIKE '%criteria%' but instead into an exact match.

Comment: I want to clear a point. If a **description** contains `'this is good car'`, this record should be fetched for **car** keyword

Comment: but if you just searched with wild cars to the right and left then you would get a match on a record containing car in the word e.g. cart, racecar, scar...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Dynamic query that will do what you want.

```
    declare @search nvarchar(max)
    declare @dyn_sql nvarchar(max)
    declare @where nvarchar(max)

    set @search = 'car 1000 london'
    set @search = rtrim(LTRIM(@search))
    set @search = REPLACE(@search,' ',',')
    set @where = ''

    while (LEN(@search) > 0)
        begin
            declare @place_holder nvarchar(100)

            if((select CHARINDEX(',',@search)) = 0)
                begin
                    set @place_holder = @search
                end
            else
                begin
                    set @place_holder = SUBSTRING(@search, 0, CHARINDEX(',',@search))
                end

            set @place_holder = REPLACE(@place_holder,',','') 

            if((select CHARINDEX(',',@search)) = 0)
                begin
                    set @search = ''
                end

            set @search = SUBSTRING(@search, CHARINDEX(',',@search)+1, LEN(@search))

            set @where = @where+'name like ''%'+@place_holder+'%'' or '
            set @where = @where+'description like ''%'+@place_holder+'%'' or '
            set @where = @where+'location like ''%'+@place_holder+'%'' or '+CHAR(10)
        end

    set @where = SUBSTRING(@where,0,len(@where)-3)

    set @dyn_sql = 
    '
    select
        *
    from
        Products
    where
        '+@where

    exec (@dyn_sql)
```